# IE9 does not update window.location.href in iFrame when using browser's back button. Workarounds?

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-9, hashchange

I am using the `onhashchange` javascript event to show the user a sequence of "screens" without reloading the page for each screen. When placing this page inside an iFrame, the hashchange event is not fired by IE9 and window.location.href is not updated as expected.

**What I expect:** Whenever the user clicks "continue" to proceed to another screen, the hash portion of the URL is changed. When the browser's back and forward buttons are used, the hash is changed by the browser. This is caught by the onhashchange event handler in javascript, and the correct content is displayed.

**What I observe instead:** The behavior in all browsers supporting the onhashchange event (including IE9) is as expected. However, when the page in question is loaded inside an iFrame, the behavior changes in IE9. Here is what happens when I click the browser's back button in IE9:

- No hashchange event is fired.
- window.location.href and window.location.hash remain the same as before clicking the back button
- If I right click the iFrame and view the iFrame's properties, the URL is shown with the changed hash. I.e. the URL in the properties window does not match window.location.href

**Toy example:** Because others report not seeing this behavior, I created a toy example here: http://jonemo.de/stuff/ie9iframe/test.html. Click `state1`, then click `state2`, click the back button of your browser. `Current state of iFrame` should read `state1`, but in my IE9 it reads `state2` after this sequence of actions. My IE is version 9.0.8112.16421, that's the normal release version.

How can I detect use of the back button on a page inside an iFrame in IE9? The pages holding the iFrame and inside the iFrame can be on different domains. I have full control over the page in the iFrame and can place arbitrary Javascript on the page holding the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` updates perfectly fine for me. If you're accessing from outside the iframe, are you sure you're accessing `iframe.contentWindow.location.href`?

Comment: If this is the case, maybe you can tell me what you are doing differently from me. I created a toy example to illustrate the problem here: http://jonemo.de/stuff/ie9iframe/test.html

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly for me. The "current state" updates instantly and the `location.href` catches up on the next second.

Comment: Even for using the browser's back button? I am confused now. I tested this on three computers, and it works on none of them. What version of IE9 do you have (I am using 9.0.8112.16421), what version of Windows (I tried Windows7 32bit and 64bit)? There must be a difference! I also found the discussion at https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/issues/17 which confirms the behavior I observe.

Comment: Oh, wait, my bad. The back button does indeed fail... I can only assume this is a glitch in how the Back button works when dealing with iframes - it's always been kind of iffy, and you can imagine what a mess it must be when there are several iframes...